# How do I overlay corresponding values over each frame of an animation?

Tags: image-processing, animation, video, overlay

I recorded a phenomenon using video capturing (`phen.avi`, imported into *Mathematica*) and simultaneous measurement of some electrical properties of that phenomenon (a list with values). For every frame, there is a corresponding value, which I would like to

a) overlay directly on each frame (is it possible to convert numbers into graphics and then use `ImageCompose[]`?); and

b) animate these values in an "electrocardiogram"-style, so values vs. "rolling time".

This should be possible with `Animate[]`, but do I have to split this animation into single images in order to overlay it onto `phen.avi`, or is there a more direct way?

Comment: You should be able to use something like `Animate[Show[frameofavi[[t]],Graphics[Text[ToString[the number you want to overlay],{xposition,yposition}]]],{t,1,Length[frameofavi},1]'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you import the avi using the option `GraphicsList` then you immediately have a variable which is a list with all the frames. For instance:

```
imagelist = Import["...file.avi","GraphicsList"]
```

You can then create an animation with this imagelist and superpose the frame numbers (or whatever other numbers you want using `Show` inside the `Animate` function):

```
Animate[Show[imagelist[[t]], Graphics[Text[ToString[t],{10,10}]]],{t,1,Length[imagelist], 1}]
```

The `{10,10}` alters where in the frame the text will appear. You can alter the `Style` of the text as you want. In this example the text which will appear is simply the frame number (`ToString[t]`) and you can alter this however you need.

Comment: Thanks that works! I just replaced the `t` in `ToString[t]` with code that selects the proper values. Nice!

Answer (score 8):

```
k = Import["traffic.avi", "ImageList"];
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];
s[n_] := ListLinePlot[a[[1 ;; n]], PlotStyle ->{Thick, White}, PlotRange ->{{1, 10}, {0, 1}}]
Table[ImageCompose[k[[n]], s[n]], {n, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your code (and particularly the PlotStyle) is very close to what I was looking for. I think for the animation style I tried to describe (regarding oscilloscopes, it's also called [roll mode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOT3-NrDrc4)), a full range plot should be slided under a fixed-width time window.

Answer (score 5):

I present a solution qualitatively similar to belisarius's, but done somewhat differently:

```
(* import an AVI frame-by-frame *)
imgs = ExampleData /@ ExampleData[{"TestAnimation", "ToyVehicles"}, "Frames"];

(* some plots *)
plots = Table[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -$MachineEpsilon, u}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True,
                   Epilog -> {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], Orange], 
                              Point[{u, Sin[u]}]},
                   FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {None, All}},
                   PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Orange],
              {u, 0, 2 π, 2 π/9}];

(* finished product *)
Animate[
  Graphics[Inset[plots[[k]], {1, 0}, {2 π + π/15, -1 - 1/8}], 
           PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
           Prolog -> {Texture[imgs[[k]]], 
                      Polygon[Scaled /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
                          VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}],
        {k, Length[imgs]}]
```

[image: some cartoon with a plot]

Here, I took care to match the aspect ratio of the enclosing `Graphics[]` with the aspect ratio of the animation; you can skip this calibration if you don't mind a few distortions. After this, I used `Inset[]` so that the graph is displayed, but does not cover up the animation. If need be, one can also use directives like `Text[]` or options like `PlotLabel` along with each frame of the final animation.

Comment: That Jeep is mine

Comment: @bel, sorry, but I didn't like Walter Cronkite, and the chemical plants remind me too much of my job. Thus...

Answer (score 4):

To get a rolling plot you can change the `PlotRange` with time, something like this:

```
(* fake movie frames *)
image[t_] := RandomImage[{0, 1}, {150, 150}]~Blur~3

(* make up some data to plot *)
data = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100}]];
range = {Min[data], Max[data]};

(* define the rolling plot *)
rollingplot[t_, n_] := ListLinePlot[data[[;; t]],
  PlotRange -> {{Max[t, n] - n + 1, Max[t, n]}, range}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier", 10, White},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Green],
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImagePadding -> 15]

Animate[ImageCompose[image[t], rollingplot[t, 25]], {t, 1, 100, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: ur cable provider is worst than mine

Comment: This is what I meant with "rolling time" - thanks! I will try to modify it, so that the graph also starts coming from the right side.